# Python "requests" library: HTTP basic authentication for each request

Tags: python, python-requests, basic-authentication

In a Python script I use the "Requests" library with HTTP basic authentication and a custom CA certificate to trust like this:

```
import requests    
response = requests.get(base_url, auth=(username, password), verify=ssl_ca_file)
```

All requests I need to make have to use these parameters. Is there a "Python" way to set these as default for all requests?

Comment: `requests` has extensive documentation on the `Session` class. Use that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Session()`. [Documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/) states:

> The Session object allows you to persist certain parameters across
>   requests.

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()
s.auth = (username, password)
s.verify = ssl_ca_file

s.get(base_url)
```